# How to add extra content to the WordPress admin user table Name column every cells

Tags: wordpress

[image]

I want to add extra information after every name, in the name columns cells, How may I do that? default columns like **names, email, role** are not pass on *manage_users_custom_column* hook. I tried the below code but not working!

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'add_extra_text_after_every_name', 10, 3 );
function add_extra_text_after_every_name( $output, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    if ( 'name' == $column_name ) {
        // is not working, because default fields name didn't pass
    }
    return $output;
}
```

thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because that field is from wordpress default swtich cases, so this never will take that filter, you can see this in the wordpress/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-users-lists-table.php line #547

```
case 'name':
if ( $user_object->first_name && $user_object->last_name ) {
    $r .= "$user_object->first_name $user_object->last_name";
} elseif ( $user_object->first_name ) {
    $r .= $user_object->first_name;
} elseif ( $user_object->last_name ) {
    $r .= $user_object->last_name;
} else {
    $r .= sprintf(
        '<span aria-hidden="true">&#8212;</span><span class="screen-reader-text">%s</span>',
        _x( 'Unknown', 'name' )
    );
}
break;
```

The only thing that you can do, is add new columns and data